# Generating of symmetric key?

Tags: cryptography

I would like to generate key for symmetrically encrypted ( AES) communication with others. Is it secure to use random number generator? Especially, for example, `/dev/urandom` provided by Linux?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's how it's usually done. Just make sure your system is properly seeded. Most distributions do this automatically, but if you're not sure, you have two choices:

1) If you only need a few bytes and only rarely, you can use `/dev/random`.

2) When your program first starts up, read `/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`. If it's greater than 512, you have nothing to worry about. You can read from `/dev/urandom` all you want and the results will be secure.

Comment: Thanks! :). What about 2)? Can I read something about it more- please refer me to somewhere? You've said a bit, but it appeared a magic number `512`, I would like to read about it.

Comment: Unfortunately, Linux has no way to do what you really want, which is to return secure random numbers blocking only if necessary. The way Linux's PRNGs work, they're secure forever so long as they've ever been seeded. 512 bytes is more than enough to permanently seed them (256 would do). So if the system has ever had more than about 256 bytes of entropy, it's secure until rebooted. Most distributions ensure this condition automatically.

Comment: just as an addition to what @DavidSchwartz wrote: please be aware of the cryptographic usecase when refering to entropy >256 is enough for trusting the PRNGS to hand out secure key bytes. while this holds for most real world scenarios (and probably for the scope of this question), it does not hold for some special cases ... for example OTP, or if the system is doing nothing but handing out keys for others ... it is still pseudo randomness, not real randomness ...

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I've checked my `/proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` and it is 378. So, it should be secure. But, can I be sure that it will be always secure? I mean the situation after reboot or situation after "pulling" 10^100 random bytes? 
Thanks guys a lot. If you recommend me something to read I will be grateful .

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42, you've said that entropy > 256 is secure but not **very** secure ( I mean for example OTP). If I should OTP service what can I do/

Comment: i did not say it's not very secure ... it is secure for most real world applications, but for some special cases, it's not enough ... the probability of you needing OTP is pretty slim... but in cases like that, you will most likely want to get your hands on a TRNG ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator

Comment: OTP is mainly a theoretical construction. In 99.9% of the cases you might as well use AES in streaming (CTR) mode or - for most protocols - an AEAD mode such as GCM.

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 I disagree. It is secure enough for *all* purposes. The difference between "real" randomness and pseudo-randomness is like the difference between holy water and regular water. Some people think they really want one rather than the other, but no known or conceivable test can tell the difference.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz well, lets have a look at something like OTP. OTP is *provable* the only cryptosystem that if you follow its rules, is unbreakable, no matter what computational resources an attacker has, because it is not possible to tell the right cleartext apart from all other possible candidates ... if you take the very same cryptosystem, and just replace real randomness by a prng output based on limited entropy, the "unbreakable" property of OTP no longer holds... so, yes, even though this *is* mainly theoretical, there are applications where a PRNG is not enough

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 This is the classic Holy water argument -- maybe you need to stab a demon so need to wash your sword with holy water. Find me a demon and we'll talk. Find the attacker that can break the PRNG and then you can argue that you can't use the PRNG because the attacker exists.

Comment: so basically you say theoretical cryptography and analysis of cryptographic strength is useless until you can actually prove that an attacker is able to break a system, then you will think of a new one ... the problem with approaches like this is: you might want to keep things secret, even though the battlefield changes in 20 years from now ... and an attacker can collect the information today and use it in the future ... forward secrecy ... so in terms of your deamon ... that thing can be waiting around the corner, or not ... when you see it, it might be too late

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 There is no choice other than to use your best judgment. If you just guess, you may defend against completely the wrong threats. Worse, you may actually wind up designing a system that's less secure than those technologies we have that are battle-hardened and widely tested because you do something that turns out to be really stupid. I am not saying that analysis is useless, only that it's possible to misuse it, and what you are suggesting would be an example of such misuse were someone to actually do it.